# how does procexp close a mutex held by another process?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to close a mutex that is being held by a process on Windows using Win32 functions. This can be done using procexp but I need to do it programmatically without using the procexp GUI.

**Method1:**
I tried injecting a dll into the processs using EasyHook and then tried the following from the injected thread:
 - OpenMutex
 - ReleaseMutex
It gave me the ERROR_NOT_OWNER error probably because the release was called on a different thread than the one that called AcquireMutex.

**Method2:**
After injecting the dll, I tried to hook for CreateMutex using mHook. The hooked CreateMutex just called back the original CreateMutex. But this would just crash the application.

I can use procexp to close the mutex but I need to do it programmatically. How does procexp do it? How can it be done programmatically without any kernel mode code?

Comment: ReleaseMutex is not the close method for it. You need to call CloseHandle on it. Do you want to unblock a mutex or close the handle to it? Process Explorer can only close it.

Comment: It is a global mutex held by a process. Would closing it allow other processes to be able to acquire it?

Comment: From the docs it is not sure but I would expect that WaitForSingleObject does succeed but with the error code WAIT_ABANDONED. If that does not work I would try to use a kernel mode driver ;-)

Comment: Why would you want to mess with the objects opened by another process? This sounds like removing a symptom, not solving the problem.

Comment: I am trying to launch two instances of the same game that disallows launch by using the mutex. We have the authorization from the game manufacturer but it is harder to get code level changes in the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [NtQuerySystemInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx) to retrieve an array of open handles, loop through the array until you find the desired mutex handle in the target process, then close it using [`DuplicateHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) by specifying the `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE` flag.

The following article explains it in more detail:

[HOWTO: Enumerate handles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b78bf61-4a06-4367-bc28-a9cba3c688b5/howto-enumerate-handles)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a complete answer. I had to add the following the following code to handles.cpp after the mutex is recognized:

```
     HANDLE realHandle;  
     ret = DuplicateHandle(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, GetCurrentProcess(), &realHandle, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);  

         if(!ret)  
               printf("DuplicateHandle Problem!");  

         if (!CloseHandle(realHandle))  
    {  
      printf("Problem closing the copied handle");  
    }  
    printf("", realHandle);  
  }
```

Comment: Obviously, do not call `CloseHandle()` if `DuplicateHandle()` fails, since there is nothing to close.  And your last `printf()` does not output anything since there is no format specifier provided.