# Close handle that is reading my file

Tags: c++, windows-7

When I try to delete a file it can sometimes be open in another program.
How do I detect which program has my file opened and how do I close their handle to my program to allow me to delete my file?

Comment: Imagine a world, where other programs were allowed to just close your file handles.

Comment: @DonReba Handles.exe from Sysinternals can do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does procexp close a mutex held by another process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292186/how-does-procexp-close-a-mutex-held-by-another-process)

Comment: @DonReba Dream world. But somehow I must be able to disallow other programs writing/reading my file

Comment: Quite possibly you can't, if for example that other program is your antivirus scanner, which is usually a system service or a kind of rootkit. That would be one likely candidate for opening "your" file (why would some other program open a random file otherwise).

Comment: @Damon Anticheat software. So what I'm trying to achieve is somewhat impossible?

Comment: @Ezzy did you try the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292186/how-does-procexp-close-a-mutex-held-by-another-process) that SerG commented about? Why did that not work?

Comment: @Ezzy: It depends, impossible to tell. If that anticheat software is worth its salt, it's a pretty futile attempt. You can go ahead and try with ProcExp like suggested by avraham shalev (fastest solution!), or follow SerG's tip. Just don't be disappointed if you find out it doesn't work (which is likely). A not totally naive anticheat software written by someone who is not a complete novice will install a driver, make itself unkillable, and hook the APIs that will let you do what you try. Plus, the game probably won't run without the anticheat software operating within normal parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sysinternals suite's ProcExp.

[download from here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

CTRL+F to search for the file handle..and right click + close handle to close it.

**make sure to run ProcExp as an Administrator!**

Answer (score 0):

If in Linux or on a Mac, use lsof. It can be used to show open files, open sockets, and more - I often use it for network stuff, instead of netstat.