# WINAPI - Close mutex without being the owner

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mutex, ownership

I'm trying to close a mutex in another application.

I'm using the WinAPI ("windows.h").

Here's my code to close this mutex:

```
DWORD pid = 0;
hMyWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "TheFamousWindowName");

GetWindowThreadProcessId(hMyWnd, &pid);

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, 0, pid);

HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, false, "TheEvilMutex"); // hMutex isn't null
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 10000); // Wait 10 seconds, nothing happens

if (!DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)) {
    // Arrive always here because of error 288
    // And the mutex is still there, not closed
}

ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

The problem is when I call

```
DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
```

I got the error 288 with

```
GetLastError()
```

labeled as "Attempt to release mutex not owned by caller" and the mutex isn't closed

Now, I know that I'm not the owner, but I can't see a solution to close this mutex.

I've seen some programs doing it like Process Explorer or Process Hacker. I've looked into the code of this last on GitHub but didn't find anything about how it close a mutex without being the owner.

I've also checked this thread 
    [how does procexp close a mutex held by another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292186/how-does-procexp-close-a-mutex-held-by-another-process) but I can't get it working.

Thanks for reading me.
Hoping someone could help me.

**EDIT** :
Thanks to @RbMm, replacing

```
DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
```

with

```
DuplicateHandle((HANDLE)-1, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
```

solved error 288, but the mutex isn't closed with this.

Comment: You can only release a mutex you have wait(ed) on: _"...or by specifying its handle in a call to one of the wait functions. ..."_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include the desired behavior and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: @tambre Thanks, I've tried to improve my question with your advice.

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why, oh why, would you like to break another application by fiddling with its mutexes? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: in call `DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex` - `hMutex` - must be handle in context of `hProc`. but `hMutex` is handle in context of your process, not `hProc`. so you really try close not `hMutex` but **arbitrary** handle value in context of `hProc`

Comment: you again mistake. `hMutex` is **closed** by call `DuplicateHandle((HANDLE)-1, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)` it have same effect as `CloseHandle(hMutex)`. another question that in `hProc` process mutex not closed. for close it - you need know it handle value in `hProc`. and again - error 288 you got not from call `DuplicateHandle` but from call `ReleaseMutex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in call `DuplicateHandle(hProc, hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)` `hMutex` must be handle that is valid in the context of the `hProc`. but `hMutex` is handle in current process, not in `hProc`. so in this line of code you try close arbitrary handle in context of `hProc`, but not your `hMutex`. and result of this will be arbitrary. may be you close some handle. may be this handle not exist at all, or handle is protected from close.

> And the mutex is still there, not closed

of course it not closed and can not be closed. for close it you need call

```
DuplicateHandle(NtCurrentProcess(), hMutex, NULL, 0, 0, false, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
```

> because of error 288

i absolute sure that `DuplicateHandle` never return this error. `ERROR_NOT_OWNER` you got from `ReleaseMutex(hMutex);`

---

for close mutex in **another** process - need use handle value of this mutex in target process, not in self process. this code is done work:

```
void CloseRemote(ULONG dwProcessId, PCWSTR Name)
{
    // create any file
    HANDLE hFile = OpenMutex(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, Name);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, dwProcessId))
        {

            NTSTATUS status;
            ULONG cb = 0x80000;

            union {
                PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pshi;
                PVOID pv;
            };

            do 
            {
                status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

                if (pv = LocalAlloc(0, cb))
                {
                    if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, pv, cb, &cb)))
                    {
                        if (ULONG_PTR NumberOfHandles = pshi->NumberOfHandles)
                        {
                            ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
                            PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX Handles = pshi->Handles;
                            do 
                            {
                                // search for created file
                                if (Handles->UniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId && Handles->HandleValue == (ULONG_PTR)hFile)
                                {
                                    // we got it !
                                    PVOID Object = Handles->Object;

                                    NumberOfHandles = pshi->NumberOfHandles, Handles = pshi->Handles;
                                    do 
                                    {
                                        if (Object == Handles->Object && Handles->UniqueProcessId == dwProcessId)
                                        {
                                            DuplicateHandle(hProcess, (HANDLE)Handles->HandleValue, 0, 0, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
                                        }

                                    } while (Handles++, --NumberOfHandles);

                                    break;
                                }
                            } while (Handles++, --NumberOfHandles);
                        }
                    }
                    LocalFree(pv);
                }

            } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - [`PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01876) is undocumented and not present in any windows headers. but you can found it definition. `STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` declared in `ntstatus.h` from wdk.

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - *ntdll.lib* file is exist. all definitions you can found in inet. for example at http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/ resource

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - what you doing ?!? you need link with `ntdll.lib`

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - your problem in zero knowledge. try understand at begin how you call api from kernel32.dll for example. how you call say `DuplicateHandle` - really how ?!?

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - no. reply me (really for yourself) - how you call `DuplicateHandle`, `OpenMutexW`, `OpenProcess` - until you not understand this you can not go forward

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - yes, you missing very many. ok. include declaration for `ZwQuerySystemInformation` *And then simply call the function* - try it. in what is problem ?

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - **NO**. forget about *ntdll.lib* until. you at all not understand what is lib file. i give you site where this api declared. if so hard found - http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l02356 - copy-paste it and call function - in what is problem ?

Comment: @PandoresStrongest ... so change `NtQuerySystemInformation` to `ZwQuerySystemInformation` or `ZwQuerySystemInformation` to `NtQuerySystemInformation` - why you so so helpless ?

Comment: @PandoresStrongest -  quit obvious only your zero knowledge and rarely helpless. repeat this point  last time - change in my code `ZwQuerySystemInformation` to `NtQuerySystemInformation` or change in function definition `NtQuerySystemInformation` to `ZwQuerySystemInformation`.and even now I will reveal to you a terrible secret only do not tell anyone - in user mode all ZwXXX and NtXXX is alias - point to the same function

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - sorry but your helpless is fantastic. i already give you link to site where all this definitions exist. also are you banned in google ? or you dont know how search word ? last time i search for you - http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01268

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - no problem. i simply try explain to you very important things - by asking question and try make you think for yourself. for call any function - you must **1** declare it for compiler. say `OpenProcess` declared in some header file, which you include. `[Zw/Nt]QuerySystemInformation` you need declare yourself. but exist also **2** - linkage. function must be **implemented** somewhere. for this is used *.lib* files. for `OpenProcess`  you need use *kernel32.lib* as linker input. for `[Zw/Nt]QuerySystemInformation` - `ntdll.lib`. and not need confuse dll and lib.

Comment: @PandoresStrongest - no any difference in call `OpenProcess` and `ZwQuerySystemInformation` or `FindWindow`. for every api need use correct lib - kernel32.lib, ntdll.lib, user32.lib. you must include it. simply in your default project settings some libs can be added by default, some libs need add direct. but need understand this process